# How to make BehaviorSubject<string> function next() emit all character of string at the same time?

Tags: angular, rxjs, behaviorsubject

I have defined the BehaviorSubject and map value like this:

```
const foo$: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject("asd");

const queryObservable = foo$.pipe(
  switchMap(x => {
    return x;
  }
  )
);

queryObservable.subscribe(x => {
  console.log(x);
});
```

In the console it print:

```
a
s
d
```

but I expect it to be:

```
asd
```

What did I got wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you want to achieve with `switchMap` and the code that you have written.

Just to answer the question, you can use `map` instead of `switchMap`

```
const foo$: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject("asd");

const queryObservable = foo$.pipe(
  map(x => {
    return x;
  }
  )
);

queryObservable.subscribe(x => {
  console.log(x);    // result should be "asd"
});
```

**OR**

A simple way would be,

```
const foo$: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject("asd");

foo$.subscribe(x => {
  console.log(x);
});
```

**OR**

with `SwitchMap` , using `of` operator

```
const foo$: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject("asd");

const queryObservable = foo$.pipe(
  switchMap(x => {
    return of(x);
  }
  )
);

queryObservable.subscribe(x => {
  console.log(x);
});
```

Comment: The last one is working. Thanks. My purpose is that I want to bind ```foo$``` with <Input type='date'> and print the selected date. The tutorial that I read use switchMap and I don't know why. What do you think? @micronyks

Comment: I'm glad it helped you ! Thanks !

Comment: `swtichMap` doesn't make sense at all but it seems still you are in a learning phase. You'll get to know `why` soon. `SwichMap` is meant for something else.